# Title of science fiction novel from the '80s or early '90s with small furry aliens

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

There was another alien species that was invading Earth, and the little furry aliens helped us out. I think they liked having sex all the time and ended up having sex with the humans as well.

Comment: We really need more details. If you visit the `story-identification` tag, you'll find links to more questions to [edit] more info into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might you be talking about Allen Dean Foster's [*Quozl*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35179.Quozl)?

[image: Front cover of the Quozl paperback]

> The Quozl knew they'd love the third planet from the sun. But it never occurred to them that anyone lived there...

The eponymous Quozl, based off of rabbits, have a stereotypical fixation on constant sex, and indeed, part of the ending indicates that they have no problem with humans being the target of this behavior...

Comment: That's the one. I remember that goofy cover